# Gulp - Handle read-only permissions for dest files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have image files with `read-only` attribute set in source folder. I need to copy them to destination folder in most cases several times in gulpfile.js.

I am trying to copy src-to-dest files like this:

```
gulp.task('copy-images', function () {
  gulp.src(path_resource_images + '**/*.jpg')
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path_app_images));
});
```

It works once when the dest folder in empty. But for all next calls I've got an exception that file is `read-only` in dest folder. How can I remove file attr `read-only` to make *image-copy* works every time I call it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use **[gulp-chmod](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-chmod)** to handle permissions on your files.

So if you want to set your images `readable` and `writable` for everybody, you could go with something like:

```
var chmod = require('gulp-chmod');

gulp.task('copy-images', function() {
  gulp.src(path_resource_images + '**/*.jpg')
    .pipe(chmod(666))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path_app_images));
});
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that this would change the attributes of the files on the stream before they are written to the dest so that they are not written as read only to begin with?

Comment: @epeleg To be more specific, vinyl files, but yeah you got the idea ;)

Comment: yes, you are right. I wanted to clarify to myself that it does not work on the file system but on the (yet-to-be-written-to-the-file-system-via-.dest) vinyl files in the stream. 10x.

Answer (score 10):

By passing [options](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulpdestpath-options) attribute. Set `mode` value to specify permission for any folders that need to be created as output.

```
gulp.dest("destination-path-here", {"mode": "0777"})
```

cheers :-)

Comment: Is there a way to do this for all gulp.dest(...) calls? A global setting, e.g.?

Answer (score 0):

[rimraf](https://github.com/isaacs/rimraf) can be used to avoid issues with TFS permissions (by deleting destination files before copying files)

```
var rimraf = require("rimraf");
gulp.task("images_clean", function (cb) {
    rimraf(imagesDest, cb);
});
```