# How to setup gulp-watch with project in TFS to avoid EPERM issue

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, tfs, gulp

I am using angularJS with bower to manage dependencies in the web UI and npm to manage bower, gulp, karam, etc. dependencies in the web UI.  The project is all stored in TFS and we are using VS2013 because we have a Web API v2 project that is returning our data from the SQL Server.  I am really enjoying the front-end tight feedback loop but now that we have added our project to TFS I continually have to:

1. Stop the gulp command in my powershell window
2. Remove the read-only permissions of the files in the "dist" folder
3. Start gulp again in my powershell window

It seems that even though the "dist" folder isn't being checked into TFS because the files gulp uses to build the files in the "dist" folder they are being set to read-only after gulp finishes.

I would prefer to not have to checkout all the files in the web UI project from TFS just so gulp, gulp-watch and livetreload will work.  I had it working before checking into TFS where I could easily change a file, save it, and then view in my browser but this no longer works because of EPERM errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using Local Workspaces in TFS that do not require read only flags.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/29/server-workspaces-vs-local-workspaces.aspx

They were introduced way back in TFS 2012. If you are using a TFS server prior to 2010 then you are unsupported already and 2010 drops out of support in a couple of months.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately they are using TFS 2010 but have talked about updating.  Good to know that TFS has gotten better and no longer requires the read only flags.  Too bad my current client is still on TFS 2010.

Comment: Make sure that they know that support runs out. I would try to convince them to go to VSO...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be an issue with TFS, it is with gulp making files read-only.  This code:

```
var chmod = require('gulp-chmod');

gulp.task('copy-images', function() {
  gulp.src(path_resource_images + '**/*.jpg')
.pipe(chmod(666))
.pipe(gulp.dest(path_app_images));
});
```

I found here: [Gulp - Handle read-only permissions for dest files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540548/gulp-handle-read-only-permissions-for-dest-files)

Comment: I like this work around!  Thanks for passing this info along Pete!