# When I run gulp command my file loses permission

Tags: node.js, gulp

I'm using Ubuntu and it's work fine but when I run the gulp command I got a problem. The file was created but Gulp changes the file permissions and the browser can't read the file. So I can't navigate in my project website. =/

[image]

My gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
//~ var gulp = require('gulp-util');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var src='./wp-content/themes/wikitricks';
var scripts=[
            src + '/js/jquery.min.js',
            src + '/js/jquery-ui.js',
            src + '/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js',
            src + '/js/featherlight.min.js',
            //~ src + '/js/jquery.masonry.min.js',
            src + '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js',
        ];

gulp.task('js', function() {

    return gulp.src(scripts)
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(src))

});

gulp.task('default', ['js'], function () {

    gulp.watch(scripts, ['js']);

});
```

Comment: My files lose permission when I `gulp watch` but when I manually run `gulp <task>` permissions are intact.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution but I still don't know why it happens...

```
var chmod = require('gulp-chmod');

gulp.task('copy-images', function() {
  gulp.src(path_resource_images + '**/*.jpg')
    .pipe(chmod(666))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path_app_images));
});
```

From: 
[Gulp - Handle read-only permissions for dest files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540548/gulp-handle-read-only-permissions-for-dest-files)